# What is the difference of a "Type A to Type C cable" and "Type A to Type A cable plus Type A to Type C connector"?

Tags: usb, macbook-pro, usb-3, connector

I have

- (A) a Harddisk box equip with TypeA connector come with a TypeA to
  TypeA cable(USB3)
- (B) a Macbook Pro of late 2017 with all ports in
  TypeC connector

```
So, for using the harddisk box, I have to add a TypeA to TypeC connector for connecting them.
TypeA<============>TypeA + [TypeA to TYPEC] Connector
```

Because there are 2 connection points plus the flaw design of Macbook Pro TypeC ports, it always lose connection.

So, I try to connect it with a TypeA to TypeC cable which is also supporting USB3.
(The cable is coming form another Harddisk box which is TypeC in native but coming with a TypeC to TypeA cable for compatibility with existing Windows machine)

```
Then I try to connect the (A) Harddisk box with this TypeC to TypeA cable.
TypeA<============>TypeC
```

The Macbook Pro does not recognize nor response.

So I would like to know what is the difference between

1. TypeA to TypeA cable plus a TypeA to TypeC connector
2. TypeC to TypeAcable (Not usable when reversing when TypeA to TypeC?)

in nature to make such difference?
And what should I do or what type of cable should I get so that the
TypeA Harddisk Box can work with a native TypeC to typeA cable?

Many thanks.

Comment: *"(A) a Harddisk box equip with TypeA connector come with a TypeA to TypeA cable(USB3)"* -- Please provide a link for such a device.  The Type-A port should only be on a host (i.e. the PC) (or a hub), and not on a USB device.

Comment: @sawdust I understand it is quite rare in design. I bought this box from Taobao: https://gd3.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/38611242/TB2VLrBclUSMeJjy1zjXXc0dXXa_!!38611242.jpg Because a usual design is usually equip with Type B. I have another Harddisk hub which have such usual design as Type B connector.

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder what is the difference by a TypeA-TypeA cable + TypeA
>   female-TypeC male connector and the TypeC-TypeA cable

The difference is this: "the TypeC-TypeA cable" is intended to be pluged into regular TypeA USB host, which is always a host. The Type-A end has no means to communicate this to Type-C end, so the Type-C end is HARDWIRED to represent itself as "USB host". For this purpose the Type-C end has 56k pullup between VBUS and CC pin (some cables have 22k or 10k, which causes troubles sometimes). So when you plug the standard "TypeC-TypeA cable" into your MacPRO, the Mac thinks that the cable is the host, and host-host connection doesn't engage, and your HDD doesn't work. And since the HDD is not a host, the MacPRO can't work as device, so nothing happens.

The "TypeA female-TypeC male connector" is a different one. Its TypeC end has 5.1k PULL DOWN, which indicates to MacPRO that there is a device attached, and the MacPRO will enable VBUS, and your TypeA HDD will start communicating. The connection, however, will be less reliable because of reduced signal integrity - extra connector causes imperfection and degrade signals. More, many "TypeA female-TypeC male connectors" are made by people who have no foggiest clue what they are doing, and internal wiring is frequently very terrible in terms of super-speed transmission line quality. This is likely why you have an unreliable connection to HDD.

To make your illegal TypeA HDD to work with a single cable with a TypeC port, you either need to find another odd TypeA to TypeC male cable with 5.1k pull-down on one of CC pins, or to make your own using available breakout TypeC assemblies and very-very careful soldering. It might work.

Answer (score 0):

> I bought this box from Taobao: https://gd3.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/38611242/TB2VLrBclUSMeJjy1zjXXc0dXXa_!!38611242.jpg

That Model 396U3 HDD enclosure is also sold on [Amazon.com by Wanlonxing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078Q2RHS9).

Since that enclosure has its own built-in power supply (so that it can support a 3.5" HDD), it does not require any power from the USB interface.  Hence its Type-A port in all likelihood has the power-pin unconnected.
So although it has a host-style USB port, that port cannot behave like a USB host.
Therefore there should be no host-to-host conflict with a USB Type-A-to-Type-A cable

> And what should I do or what type of cable should I get so that the TypeA Harddisk Box can work with a native TypeC to typeA cable?

According a Q&A answer by the seller (Wanlongxin Seller on November 28, 2018) on Amazon, this enclosure does not work with a host Type-C connection.

> **Question**: Is this case backward compatible with USB 2.0?
>
> **Answer**: Yes, this case backward compatible with USB 2.0. But not compatible with Type-C.

Comment: But, why when I add a TypeA to TypeC connector, it work instead?

Comment: *"... it work instead"* -- Previously you wrote that *"it always lose connection"*.  So what's your definition of *"work"*?

Comment: sorry for my poor description, it lose connection due to there are 2 points of connection plus the poor design of Type C connector in Macbook Pro 2017 without magnet to tighten it. "It work" means the Macbook Pro recognize the drive and I can use it for long time(such as 48hours by opening it to sync data) without moving the cable to interrupt due to the loose connection points. So that I wonder what is the difference by a TypeA-TypeA cable + TypeA female-TypeC male connector and the TypeC-TypeA cable.

Comment: You have only tested with one Type-C to Type-A cable, and it may be of dubious functionality.  Is this cable certified to meet any USB3.x specification?

Comment: I have tested 2 Type-C to Type-A cable. Both of them connecting with other devices to mac without problem. One of it is surely to be USB3 certified which come with another USB3 HD Mini Box which come with TypeC port, that box is running with SSD 2.5" inside. Another experiment is that when I connect the TypeC-TypeA cable with my LG phone. The TypeC side connected to my phone and the TypeA side plus a TypeA-TypeC connector to Macbook pro. It detect the phone and charge is beginning with USB logo. But, if I connect the A>C connector to the phone. Does not charge. It shows USB logo only.